# How to get pcre 8.x on Ubuntu 10.04 (Linode)

Tags: apt, linode, pcre

I'm trying to set up Bug Genie 3.x on my Linode server, and it is complaining because I have pcre 7.8 instead of 8.x. Doing an apt-get update and upgrade doesn't help and says that I have the latest version of libpcre3. Am I supposed to install something else, or is 7.8 the latest version in the apt-get libraries right now?

I'd be comfortable building from source *if* someone can supply very detailed instructions, but otherwise I'd probably end up making a big mess, and would rather use apt-get anyway.

Note that this will have to work with a standard LAMP stack (apache/php), so if there's any gotchas there that anyone knows about, I'd greatly appreciate any heads up that can reduce my headaches later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 11.04 includes [libpcre3 8.12](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libpcre3&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all). You could use [Ubuntu Backports](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports) to get this PCRE version on your system.

Comment: Thanks, this would be the general answer for getting it, so thanks for that, but it doesn't look like libpcre3 is available on the backports for lucid. I could submit a request and wait for that to get filled, but since the server is non-critical I just decided to do an in-place upgrade to 11.04, which of course did the trick.